# Share a web project between subdomains on Azure Websites

Tags: .htaccess, azure, subdomain, azure-web-app-service

I would like to create the following scenario in my web project, but as I am not pro web developer I don't know how to handle this.

Let's assume that I have project with main domain:

`http://foobar.com` and on this I have a links to the following subdomains:

`http://xx.foobar.com`

`http://yy.foobar.com`

I would like to that every site hosted on subdomains used the same code with only one different parameter sent to the subdomain from main page. This parameter will be a JavaScript variable. I am using `Azure Web Sites` from my project. The main question here is how to manage the code (now I am using Continuos Integration with GitHub) through these subdomains (the source code for every subdomain would be the same, except this one variable). Where should I start to search / read?

Comment: what framework and language do you use?

Comment: pure front-end without backend

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing any value for the parameter? Or is it just a static parameter? If it's static, you could possibly use JavaScript code to read the subdomain name in the URL.

Not sure what language you're using on the server, but you should also able to read the subdomain via server-side code.

But if its value is dynamic, the main page with the links can generate a QueryString parameter to pass along in the URL. Your implantation will vary depending on what language you've selected.

**UPDATED**, with additional info:

When you say "share the project source code between subdomains", do you mean that you want to deploy the same web app to multiple endpoints?

If so, you can create a separate Web App in Azure (formerly known as Azure Web Site) for each corresponding subdomain, and set up your source control to deploy to both of them whenever you check in your code.

References:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

Since you have no server-side code, I'm using you have only HTML/JavaScript/CSS files. So, you can write JavaScript code to read the parameter from the URL.

References:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp
- http://www.cssmojo.com/the_location_object/

As I mentioned earler, you would set up the links on the main index page to pass in QueryString parameters:

e.g.

- Link 1: http://sub1.mywebsite.com/?param1
- Link 2: http://sub2.mywebsite.com/?param2

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am not using any kind of backend language the main question is how to share the project source code between subdomains, I will be passing only string as a variable.

Comment: I updated the answer with additional info, since the comment space is too small for it. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you point your domain to your azure website using wildcard ([references](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/))

Second, in your html head, find the subdomain using javascript and assign in to the variable you want to use

```
var full_url = window.location.host; // e.g. subdomain.host.com
var parts = full.split('.'); // split it
var subdomain = parts[0];
```

now you can use the `subdomain` variable to change your website based on `subdomain` value (e.g. change the content)

Comment: don't forget to accept this as answer if it works so it will also help people that have the same problem